Passing UI and Click events in multi module app using Android Jetpack compose
I'm working on a scenario with Jetpack Compose where I dynamically generate the UI based on the details of Android UI components (data) received from an API response. I've created a separate module for UI generation, and I pass the API response as an input parameter to this module. I need to develop multiple screens based on the API response. Once a UI is generated for a particular API response, I need to return this dynamically generated UI back to the main app.
I'm able to generate the UI for the API response. I'm unsure about how to return the generated UI back to the main app. Additionally, the generated UI includes click actions that need to be handled, and these actions also need to be invoked on the main app.
How can I achieve these two things in Jetpack Compose? I am new to Jetpack Compose. Any help or guidance would be deeply appreciated and I would be very thankful.

Compose UI cannot be passed around, it is static in that regard. Instead you have compose functions that you call. They are self-contained, they have no other dependencies than their parameters and they have no state (except the one provided by the compose framework, like remembered values).
Compose functions are generally intended to be public top-level functions. They can be nested and are only called when and where needed. You cannot prepare a part of the UI, pass it to where it is needed and display it there, that's not how it works. Instead just call what you need and let Compose handle the rest.
You can read Thinking in Compose for more.
